# how to connect micro to µPD6379A (NEC Dac IC)

Tags: stm32, dac

We want to use µPD6379A in our project. after a lot of search we've found no data (code example or schematic hint) about using it on internet.
Can anyone guide us on using that IC.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wires tend to be good for connecting devices together. For more detailed information, some datasheets would be helpful.

Comment: [Why do you want to use a 25 year old part for which you have no data?](http://www.chipfind.ru/datasheet/pdf/nec/upd6379.pdf)

Comment: That datasheet has an example circuit and a description of the communication protocol and data format.  That's probably the best you can expect.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, thanks. I mean detailed connection and some code example

Comment: @JRE Thank you for the link, I want example of using that. some code example about how to send data to it. (data transmission protocol)